# Animate Svg Path D coordinates when active or in hover

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

[EffectAnim](https://giphy.com/gifs/lS7aVmg0FNZQPSVCcr)

I've killed myself trying to do the animations with the SVG but I can't understand how it works and I can't get good information about it.

What I am trying to do is that when an element `Li` is active or in hover the SVG changes the strings of the points in a time of 1 sec.

I tried with CSS and I did something but I can't make them Responsive.

The idea is to change the coordinates `d="M 299 50 C 299 50 303 22 272 22 L 269 22 C 269 22 241 22 241 50 C 241 78 270 78 270 78 L 272 78 C 303 78 299 50 299 50 Z"` at coordinates `d="M 300 0 C 300 0 301 22 272 22 L 28 22 C 28 22 0 22 0 50 C 0 78 29 78 29 78 L 272 78 C 301 78 300 100 300 100 Z"` at the time of making Hover or what `Li` is active. Keeping in mind the responsive desing.

If you have any documentation on which you can support me it would be excellent

```html
<svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #29abe2;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Mesa de trabajo 1</title>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z">
    <animate 
      attributeName="d"
      from="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z"
      to="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" 
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: All the pros use this to animate SVG: https://greensock.com/

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is along these lines: https://greensock.com/morphsvg/

Comment: I'm confused about what you want here. Just begin="mouseover" or something more than that?

Comment: I am seeing the JS tool, and I like it, however I would not like to fill the project with too much JS and that is why I try to do it only with SVG and CSS, try the `begin="mouseover"` and it works, but when the element is active what do I do? What I'm really looking for is to understand SVG to do the animation on my own

Comment: What do you want should happen?

Comment: The idea is to change the coordinates when is Hover or active. If not maintain the initial position

Comment: The co-ordinates do change. There's a different shape that forms on hover.

Comment: I think I don't explain myself correctly. What I want is for the effect to start when the `li` is entered in `:Hover` or when it is `:active`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I don't explain myself correctly. What I want is for the effect to start when the li is entered in `:Hover` or when it is `:active`

`:active` applies to links. And you can't have an active link unless you are hovering anyway.  So I am going to assume you mean when the menu/tab item is selected.

Here's how to do it with a little CSS and a tiny bit of Javascript.  All the Javascript does is set the correct `<li>` to active by adding a class "active" to whichever one you click on.  You don't have to use this exact code for that.  For instance you could control which `<li>` element has that class using a UX library such as Angular or Vue.

How the rest of it works is explained in the code itself.

Hope this helps.

```js
// Add a click handler for each <li>
document.querySelectorAll("ul.menu li").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    // When user clicks on an LI, we give it the class "active" and
    // remove the class "active" from the last one (if any) that had it.
    clearActive();
    evt.target.closest("li").classList.add("active");
  })
});

// Remove the class "active" from all <li> elements
function clearActive() {
  document.querySelectorAll("ul.menu li").forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.cls-1 {
  fill: #29abe2;
}

/* Hide the second path ("open") by default. */
ul.menu li svg .open {
  display: none;
}

/* When SVG has class "active" we hide the animated path, and show the second static one. */
ul.menu li.active svg .anim {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li.active svg .open {
  display: block;
}



ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
      <path class="cls-1 anim" d="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z">
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          to="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" 
          dur="1s"
          begin="mouseover"
          fill="freeze"/>
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          to="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z"
          dur="1s"
          begin="mouseout"
          fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
      <!-- A second version of the path that has the destination shape. We will display this when SVG has the "active" class. -->
      <path class="cls-1 open" d="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" />
    </svg>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
      <path class="cls-1 anim" d="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z">
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          to="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" 
          dur="1s"
          begin="mouseover"
          fill="freeze"/>
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          to="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z"
          dur="1s"
          begin="mouseout"
          fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
      <path class="cls-1 open" d="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" />
    </svg>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
      <path class="cls-1 anim" d="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z">
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          to="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" 
          dur="1s"
          begin="mouseover"
          fill="freeze"/>
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          to="M299,50s4-28-27-28h-3s-28,0-28,28,29,28,29,28h2c31,0,27-28,27-28Z"
          dur="1s"
          begin="mouseout"
          fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
      <path class="cls-1 open" d="M300,0s1,22-28,22H28S0,22,0,50,29,78,29,78H272c29,0,28,22,28,22Z" />
    </svg>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked great, I did not know that I could add 2 <animate> to the SVG, I already understand how SVG works although the truth is that it is complicated